# Why LastModifiedbyid in Trigger.new gives old value

Tags: trigger

I have noticed the strange behaviour of salesforce due to which even my code broke down in production.

I was trying to stop the user from updating some field..I used before udpate trigger and code like `Trigger.new[i].LastModifiedbyId`..

Ideally it should give the current user in `Trigger.new[i].LastModifiedbyId` in  but it gives `oldrecordLastModifiedbyId`..

Although `userinfo.getuserid` resolves the problem later.

Any idea about this behaviour of salesforce.

Comment: I feel like this post should be protected :)

Comment: @highfive They're really to prevent a bunch of first time posters adding "Thanks!" If we see a bunch of those pop up, we'll protect it!

Comment: Oh ok, got the idea

Answer (score 16, accepted):

System audit fields like LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, and SystemModStamp are not updated until later in the transaction. You shouldn't rely on any of those values being set, especially in a "before" trigger; even OwnerId might have the wrong value during a trigger, especially if assignment rules are going to be evaluated. Using UserInfo.getUserId() is the most accurate way to determine the current user modifying a record.

Edit: The fields LastModifiedById and LastModifiedDate, at least, appear to be set during step 6 (temporary save to database) in the [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) document. This means that an after trigger should, in theory, be able to perform the validations you're looking. Validation rules and before triggers are executed before this temporary record save, and will definitely see the wrong values.

Comment: So where *does* it get set in the [Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks for pointing that out. I went ahead and tracked it down by empirical evidence. Since it's not clearly documented, however, I guess it could change at any time...