# Why does lastModifiedById is same on Trigger.OldMap and Trigger.NewMap in before update trigger

Tags: trigger, case, before-trigger

I am writing a **before update trigger** on case object.
And I am debugging the LastModified by ID in case of Trigger.oldMap and Trigger.newMap. 
I was expecting them to be different values. 
But I am getting the same values in both the cases (**In case of Before update trigger**). 
But, if I compare other fields that are modified like subject, I am getting the different values in both the maps.
I am not able to understand the reason for the same.
Has anyone ever faced the same issue?

Comment: It won't change until after the records commit to the database. You can get the running user via `UserInfo.getUserId()`.

Comment: Until trigger.new record is commit in DB, you get same value.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that it's because the record technically wouldn't have been modified as nothing has been committed. Therefore, I'd suggest running the Trigger as `after update` to see if there's any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been asked and answered: [Why LastModifiedbyid in Trigger.new gives old value](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120795/why-lastmodifiedbyid-in-trigger-new-gives-old-value) It sounds like `@sfdcfox` determined that `LastModifiedById` should be set by the time you reach your `after` triggers.

However, it shouldn't really matter. If you want to determine if the user *currently modifying the record* is different than the last person to do so, you should simply compare to `UserInfo.getUserId()`, not `LastModifiedById`.

**Works**

```
for (MyObject__c newRecord : trigger.new)
{
    if (newRecord.LastModifiedById != UserInfo.getUserId())
    {
        // this strategy will correctly determine when LastModifiedById will change
    }
}
```

**Fails**

```
for (MyObject__c newRecord : trigger.new)
{
    if (newRecord.LastModifiedById != trigger.oldMap.get(newRecord.Id).LastModifiedById)
    {
        // this strategy will fail to detect changes to LastModifiedById
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is about execution of order in apex. Your before triggers run before data saved to database but LastModifiedBy will be changed after record has been saved. You can check more about execution order on this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) Also this is the reason you can't read record id in a before insert trigger.